# Can't find specific header using requests

Tags: python, python-requests

I've never worked with headers before so I'm not entirely sure how to navigate around this concept.  So far, this is what I have:

```py
from requests import get

    
headers = get("https://vidstream.pro/download/26J3NXZV3JRD").headers

print(headers)
```

Output:

```
{'Date': 'Tue, 24 Nov 2020 17:12:50 GMT', 'Content-Type': 'text/html; charset=UTF-8', 'Transfer-Encoding': 'chunked', 'Connection': 'keep-alive', 'Set-Cookie': '__cfduid=de19002bc82cc0152df0e675967904edd1606237969; expires=Thu, 24-Dec-20 17:12:49 GMT; path=/; domain=.vidstream.pro; HttpOnly; SameSite=Lax, ss=0f822c119ef8358061bd2aab0d866733; path=/', 'x-dmc': 'b0', 'CF-Cache-Status': 'DYNAMIC', 'cf-request-id': '069cd7764a0000efdc3498c000000001', 'Expect-CT': 'max-age=604800, report-uri="https://report-uri.cloudflare.com/cdn-cgi/beacon/expect-ct"', 'Report-To': '{"endpoints":[{"url":"https:\\/\\/a.nel.cloudflare.com\\/report?s=KaXnb7QE%2ByEEvl4PXrBbY68uoj54uTnJLml8TqjShKgAvv2C6hxr6%2BoIkyciuNS4MDrviGrczaSVVD02TGd0hPGph8KSxf2DRS4QdPM%2F"}],"group":"cf-nel","max_age":604800}', 'NEL': '{"report_to":"cf-nel","max_age":604800}', 'Server': 'cloudflare', 'CF-RAY': '5f74c1d0780aefdc-EWR', 'Content-Encoding': 'gzip'}
```

But when I do:

```py
print(headers.get("location"))
```

to grab the one piece of information that I need from [here](https://vidstream.pro/download/26J3NXZV3JRD):

[image: img]

it returns `None` because it can't find it.

I was wondering if headers could be hidden using Javascript. I'm really unsure of how to do this.

Comment: There is no 'location' key in the `headers` dictionary printout that you have in your question

Comment: @Steve ahh you're right.  That's wierd because it's in the headers in the image.  I'm trying to find the contents of the header `location` but it seems to be hidden when using `requests`.

Comment: Nothing is "hidden".  There is only a HTTP request, and a corresponding response.  What you get back in the response is purely determined by what was in the request.  You can see what headers Requests is sending by performing a request, and then doing this with the response:  `print(r.request.headers)`

Comment: @Steve ok you are right.  i looked more into it and it turns out that the headers actually end up changing if you click on the "download" button a few times.  im guessing it has to ping or post a request to the actual download link maybe or its due to the ads interfering at first im really not too sure.